# Adjusting Imageview size in the ImageGallery(thumbnail scroller) according to Screen Size

Tags: android, android-imageview, image-gallery

I have the Image Gallery with Small image as thumbnails , currently i have fixed the size of the image in ImageAdapter Class and its visible perfectly in small screens 240 x 320 and 320 x 480 .

But Image are displayed small in large screen Like in Tablets or in Galaxy, So how should i change the imageview size according to the screen resolution .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/img_grid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/back_up_layout"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

use this it will automatically adjust according to screen size 
i think its use full for you :)

Comment: But currently I am using gallery , can u please tell me how to do that in LinearLayout . i need to set it dynamically

Comment: then use this code 
density= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
  
   if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW)
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

and you get all screen size according to screen size just give then condition of height and weight